# PHP fputcsv to .xls with style

Tags: php, excel, fputcsv

I am trying to export some data to an excel sheet using fputcsv on PHP. I know that .csv files do not support style. If there any way I can add style to that file by saving the file as .xls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV and XLS formats are totally different. So if you want to add style, you have to create an XLS file (and forget `fputcsv` :/ ).

Have a look to [PhpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: PhPExcel is deprecated, take a look at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet