# Use Laravel to Download table as xls

Tags: laravel, xls

I want to download the data of table in excel file

I have an application in Laravel and I want to add a functionality that download user data in .xls format

```
Route::get('users/download', function(){

    $table = App\User::all();
    $filename = "User.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, array('ID', 'User Name'));

    foreach($table as $row) {
        fputcsv($handle, array($row['id'], $row['username']));
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv'
    );
    return Response::download($filename, 'User.csv', $headers);
});
```

This code works fine for .csv files what changes are required for .xls file?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573116/php-fputcsv-to-xls-with-style

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Laravel Excel: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Its very easy to use with Laravel.